# How to write Emoji on image using imagettftext()?

Tags: php, emoji

I want to use `imagettftext()` to put Emoji on image (some users use Emoji as username, such as `Summer`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to accomplish exactly the same, but based on *cleong*'s answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707654/php-imagettftext-and-specific-emoji) I'm assuming that I won't be possible.

Here is what he said:

> I don't think it's going to work. GD doesn't currently recognize UCS-4 CMAP. It'll fall back to using a UCS-2 CMAP. Characters beyond the BMP aren't reachable.