# draw image/emoji to position of actual emoji

Tags: php, image, emoji

Currently I'm writing some text to an image with imagefttext in PHP.

Sometimes I have a text with an emoji in it and I'm just removing it, because I can't draw it in a nice way.

Now I want replace the emoji from the text with the actual image of the emoji, so the text looks on the image like it should look "normal" on a smartphone.

But now I'm despairing on how can I replace an emoji image with the correct emoji in the text.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391005/php-function-imagettftext-to-write-text-with-smileys and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707654/php-imagettftext-and-specific-emoji

Comment: well ... no it's not the same thing, I want to replace the text emoji with an image emoji but I don't know how to calculate the correct position

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I've an answer for you, that might help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split your text, create separate images for the text-parts, load your emoji-png at the end of each text-part and combine all these into one image.

Example: `Hello world! :-) Foo bar :-P`

So you create a `imagefttext` for `Hello World!` and use it's right x/y coordinates for the `:-)PNG`. Do the same for `Foo bar` and `:-P`

Here's an example how to merge that into one image: [How to merge multiple images and text into single image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034428/how-to-merge-multiple-images-and-text-into-single-image)